# returning empty cell if minimum of a range contains all empty values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula which find minimum date values from AF4 to next empty cell in A starting from A4.

```
=MIN(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(AF4);COLUMN(AF4))&":af"& (MIN(IF(A4:A108="";ROW(A4:A108))))))
```

I want my formula to have if else function and if there is a value in AF4 to next empty cell in A, formula should return minimum as it does above.

If all the values are empty then i would like that the formula returns empty which is still in constraints of the formula above and not a standard date which is 00.01.1900. So basically i need an else function to this formula which returns empty cell.

How can i do this?

**EDIT**:I want my formula to work if there are any date values between the range in my formula. If there are no date values in the range, then it should show the empty string. It should be then something like =If myformula(which searches min date in range) else if there is no date in range then it should show empty string " "

Comment: Duplicate of [finding correct minimum date in a range specified in formula which may contain just string values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49893836/finding-correct-minimum-date-in-a-range-specified-in-formula-which-may-contain-j) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894901/finding-percentage-of-the-filled-values-in-a-dynamic-range

Answer (score 0):

You can't return an Empty Cell, as a cell with a formula in it is not empty.  You will get a default value of `0` instead.

You can, however, return an empty string, `""`: `=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",A1)`

Comment: i am struggling to put a if statement, which will give me the minimum date in the rage of my formula and if there is no date in the range then it leaves the cell empty. The range is starting from AF4. What does the formula that you give do? How can i insert it to my formula?

Comment: So, you want `=IF(` your `MIN(..)` formula is `=0,` then show your `MIN(..),` otherwise show the empty string `"")`?

Comment: i want my formula to work if there are any date values between the range in my formula. If there are no date values in the range, then it should show the empty string. It should be then something like  =If myformula(which searches min date in range) else if there is no date in range then it should show empty string " "